# Avoiding horizontal scroll in desktop view in html/css

Tags: html, css, media-queries, horizontal-scrolling

I am working website in which I do wan't any horizontal scroll in the desktop view whereas the mobile view looks perfect (it should be scrolling).

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6gkejud/6/embedded/result/) for it so that its easy to make changes.

The desktop view which I want in the fiddle is:

[image]

The CSS codes which I have used in the fiddle in order to get the horizontal scroll is:

```
.squares {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle above so that in the desktop view there is no horizontal scroll. The mobile view looks perfect in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6gkejud/2/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries to change your CSS to include `overflow-x:hidden`, instead of `overflow-x:auto`

**EDIT:**

You want this...

```
@media screen and(min-width:769px) {
    .squares {
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
 }
```

That targets anything over tablet size (but not a portrait ipad), hope this helps.

Comment: I am pretty sure the CSS codes will go inside it `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 
. 

}` but I am not sure what exact code will go here. Sorry, I am not good with media queries.

Comment: I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661303/how-to-horizontally-scroll-the-contents-in-mobile-tablet-view-in-html-css/50661405?noredirect=1#comment88333103_50661405). I am wondering if you can help me out.